# Can some explain below formula of excluding weekends counting

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field, validation-rule

Can some explain below formula of excluding weekends counting, I want the explanation I'm not able to understand the below formula.

The formula is :

```
  CASE(MOD(   ActivityDate - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 

0 , CASE( MOD(TODAY()-ActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
1 , CASE( MOD( TODAY()-ActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
2 , CASE( MOD( TODAY()-ActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
3 , CASE( MOD( TODAY()-ActivityDate,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
4 , CASE( MOD( TODAY()-ActivityDate ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
5 , CASE( MOD( TODAY()-ActivityDate ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
6 , CASE( MOD( TODAY()-ActivityDate ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR((TODAY()-ActivityDate)/7)*5)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

For understanding, we can break down the formula into smaller parts and understand each part separately.

The formula consists of three main parts: a **CASE** function, a **FLOOR** function, and a subtraction operation.

1. The **CASE** function evaluates the day of the week of the `ActivityDate` and the `TODAY` date, and returns the number of weekdays between them.
2. The **FLOOR** function calculates the number of full weeks between the `ActivityDate` and the `TODAY` date, and multiplies it by `5` to get the number of weekdays in those weeks.
3. The subtraction operation subtracts `1` from the total number of weekdays to exclude the `ActivityDate` itself.

The below explanation of each part of the formula:

- The formula starts with the **CASE** function, which has the following syntax:

  `CASE(expression, value1, result1, value2, result2,..., else_result)`
- The expression is:

  `MOD(ActivityDate - DATE(1985,6,24),7)`
- This expression calculates the day of the week of the `ActivityDate`, by subtracting a fixed date (1985-06-24) that is a Monday, and taking the remainder after dividing by 7. The result is a number from 0 to 6, where 0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, and so on.
- The value1, result1, value2, result2, and so on, are pairs of values and results that correspond to different cases. For each case, the value is compared with the expression, and if they match, the result is returned. For example, the first case is:

  `0 , CASE( MOD(TODAY()-ActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1)`
- This case means that if the expression is 0, which means the `ActivityDate` is a Monday, then the result is another `CASE` function, which evaluates the day of the week of the `TODAY` date, and returns the number of weekdays between the `ActivityDate` and the `TODAY` date, excluding the `ActivityDate` itself.
- For example, if the `TODAY` date is a Wednesday, the result is 2,
  because there are two weekdays (Tuesday and Wednesday) between Monday
  and Wednesday, excluding Monday.
- The other cases are similar, but they have different values and results depending on the day of the week of the `ActivityDate`. The last case is:

  `999`
- This case means that if none of the previous cases match, the result is `999`, which is an invalid value that indicates an error.
- The formula then adds the result of the `CASE` function to the result of the `FLOOR` function, which has the following syntax:

  `FLOOR((TODAY()-ActivityDate)/7)*5`
- This function calculates the number of full weeks between the `ActivityDate` and the `TODAY` date, by subtracting the `ActivityDate` from the `TODAY` date and dividing by `7`. The `FLOOR` function rounds down the result to the nearest integer. The result is then multiplied by `5` to get the number of weekdays in those full weeks.
- For example, if the `ActivityDate` is 2021-09-13 (a Monday) and the `TODAY` date is 2021-09-29 (a Wednesday), the result is 10, because there are two full weeks (2021-09-13 to 2021-09-19 and 2021-09-20 to 2021-09-26) between them, and 10 weekdays in those weeks.
- The formula then subtracts `1` from the sum of the `CASE` function and the `FLOOR` function, to exclude the `ActivityDate` itself from the count. For example, if the `ActivityDate` is 2021-09-13 (a Monday) and the `TODAY` date is 2021-09-29 (a Wednesday), the final result is 11, because there are 12 weekdays between them, excluding the `ActivityDate` itself.